# Why does my if and else statement print at the same time?

Tags: javascript

Why does the else and if statement print? Checking if arrays have matching
elements on line 5 which they do...so just my if statement should print.
However my alert condition prints with the if condition.I've tried rearranging code,still no luck.

```
var array1 = [1, 89, 3, 4, 5];

var array2 = [1, 2, 7, 10, 89];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                "Hello World" //Should just print this since elements match
            break;
        } else {
            alert("Error");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format that code..... oO

Comment: Well, the condition is falsy five out of six times, so why wouldn't it alert? What you've got there is a **loop**, the condition runs multiple times.

Comment: The `break` statement only breaks out of the `j` loop, the `i` loop keeps repeating.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the outer loop when you find a match in the inner loop, you need to give a label parameter to `break`.

```
outer:
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                "Hello World" //Should just print this since elements match
            break outer;
        } else {
            alert("Error");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You still may get some alerts before `Hello World` is displayed. Your code alerts for every non-matching pair of elements until it finds a match. So unless the matching elements are first in both arrays, you'll get a bunch of alerts before it displays `Hello world`.

Also, since you have `break` in both the `if` and `else` blocks, you'll never get past the first iteration of the `j` loop.

If you just want a single alert that indicates that no matching elements were found, you need to move it out of the loop.

```
var match_found = false;
outer:
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                "Hello World" //Should just print this since elements match
            match_found = true;
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
if (!match_found) {
    alert("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a for loop will repeat very quickly, which is why you can not see the them doing it at diffrent times; 
your code does not output at the same time, it is just to fast.

if you are looking into delay, take a look at [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the else part. You don't really need that. Unless you wish to do something else if the condition is not true, omit the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `break` it only terminates the inner loop. The outer loop will continue to iterate, your conditions will be checked again, and then the `else` statements run instead.

An alternative way to do this would be:

```
(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            "Hello World" //Should just print this since elements match
                return;
            } else {
                alert("Error");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Wrapping the code in a self executing function allows you to replace `break` with `return` to exit the entire function.

Comment: I'll try that..however what would I do if i needed a function with parameters?

Comment: I figured it out both conditions were true,thats why they both kept showing up.Some matched and some didn't.